# Settings timezone in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to display a time which is stored in MySQL database, with a specific timezone.

```
$time = '2014-01-20 21:40:13';
```

*Is there any way to print this time in `GMT+5.30 or Asia/Kolkata (timezone)` ?*

Comment: What TZ a date in database is in?

Comment: i got some records which is stored in my database, and i want to display the time in that records with a specific timezone, And i've seen "date_default_timezone_set()" but i dont think its enough for this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object oriented style

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

Procedural style

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01', timezone_open('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

[Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: [straight from the documentation, just as i like it](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Answer (score 4):

`date_default_timezone_set( )` function with the requires time zone as argument in single quotes, all the `date()` following below will display the time in the requested time zone

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); //Returns IST
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have MySQL return the time in `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` UNIX timestamp and use the PHP DateTime to format it to the timezone you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try the code........**

<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');?>

More detail here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
```